# Populate Options in Searchable Dropdown from the Data in Google Sheets for GAS Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have been having some issues with populating the options of a searchable dropdown from the data stored in Google Sheets.

To check if the functions were working properly, I tried populating it for a normal dropdown, and it was working just fine, but as soon as I changed the HTML elements to get a searchable dropdown, I stopped seeing my options in the dropdown.

*Following is my code:*

funtions.gs:

```
    function getSalesCaseOwnerDropdown(){
    
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const ws = ss.getSheetByName("CaseOwners");
    return ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();

}
```

uform.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
</head>

  <body>
  
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="sales-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#sales" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="sales" aria-selected="false">Sales</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="purchase-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#purchase" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="purchase" aria-selected="false">Purchase</button>
  </li>
   <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact Details</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sales" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="sales-tab">
    
    <br><h3 class="display-6">New Sales Case</h3>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" id="inputSales-CaseOwner">

          </select>
        </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

     <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
   
   <script>

function afterFormLoadsSalesCaseOwner(){

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSalesDropdownReturned).getSalesCaseOwnerDropdown();

    }

    
   function afterSalesDropdownReturned(arrayOfArrays) {
      var item = document.getElementById("inputSales-CaseOwner");

      arrayOfArrays.forEach(function(r) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.textContent = r[0];
        item.appendChild(option);

      });


    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",afterFormLoadsSalesCaseOwner);

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I am getting with The Searchable Dropdown:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC7tW.png)

What I am getting with Normal Dropdown:

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Sn5.png)

I need the results that are populating in Image 2 to populate in Image 1.

Any help will be highly appreciated!! Thank you guys in Advance!!

Comment: Try an [mcve] that's minimal and will allow us to reproduce the problem and please remove all extraneous stuff.  I personally won't read it if you don't.

Comment: It probably doesn't help that you import two different versions of bootstrap, and you have popper.js twice (in the bundle and stand alone)

Comment: Does the JS console show any errors?

Comment: No, it does not show any errors @Aerials